# How I can do this in Crystal Reports?

Tags: if-statement, count, crystal-reports, report

I have to create a formula to limit the registrtions in my report.
it is something like this:

```
If {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}< '00' then 
   {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}
Else

If {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte} > '00'  then 
   {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}
Else 

If {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}  > '04'then 
""

Else 
if {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}< '04' then {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: May you elaborate about what "but it does not work" means? Do you get an error message? Or an unexpected behaviour? At a glance, it looks like you are trying to compare integers with strings. Maybe you need to convert the values before compare them.

Comment: `Doesn't work` means? any error or not an expected result? what is exact issue

Comment: It would also help to know if you are trying to use this formula to filter record selection, suppress records from printing, or to determine a value to print for a field.

Comment: The result was not what i expect.

Comment: my guess is {sp_rep_comite.vnumero_cte} is not a text field?